# Probability of two sets of plates

Tags: probability, statistics

So about a day or two ago i was driving and saw another car with a license plate almost identical to mine, so i asked myself the following questions:

1)What is the probability that 2 license plates have the first 5 of their seven characters the same where the first 4 characters are exclusively letters with replacement and the last 3 characters are exclusively numbers with replacement. Ex: GDWW346

2) same question but any 5 of the 7 characters th same with the same restrictions on the formation of the plate.

Attempted solution:

1) so my first thought was to get the entire sample space: sample space = $24 X 24 X 24 X 24 X 10 X 10 X 10 = 331776000$(call this S) Next i simplified the problem and asked myself how many different plates could arise from the first 5 characters being fixed: $10 X 10 = 100$(call this E) with each of those 10's coming from the last two places on the plate. Now this is where i am not sure how to proceed because what i found was the number of ways in which one plate could arise with th first 5 spots fixed. Now my temptation is to say that for 2 plates to be the same the probability would be $$ P(event) = \frac{E}{S} (2) $$, but my gut is telling me that woukd not be the case. Thoughts?

Comment: I have not checked your math, but the idea seems OK. I guess you use 24 instead of 26 because your state/province/country does not use letters I or O. In practice, also excluded are 4-letter combinations of letters that someone in authority feels are unsuitable for display on license plates. In California we have 3-letter sequences and astonishingly many of them Bowdlerized. Also bear in mind that plates may be assigned sequentially and regionally, so the plates you see are likely far from a random sample.

Comment: For whatever reason or another i was thinking 24,  but it is actually 26 here in Ontario. I should've taken account of the fact that plates are assigned in a certain fashion, but i guess to make sure i have the basic idea, this .would be the right approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't say that the first car has a **particular** number. It can have **any** number, and it is only the second car that has to have the same number, thus Pr = E/S.

I have, of course, assumed that for whatever reason, only 24 letters are permissible in your area.

Now do the 2nd part similarly.

Comment: How much would it change if it was for a particular number?

Comment: It would become $ (E/S)\times (E/S) = (E/S)^2$